# diff or vim -d colorscheme

Tags: vimdiff, vimrc

I need a readable colorscheme for *vim -d* (or vimdiff). My problem is that some lines aren't readable (see picture), white text on yellow background:
[image]
I tried also the following in *~/.vimrc*:

```
if &diff
   set At_Co=16
   set syntax off
   colorscheme vcbc
endif
```

I like syntax on and the change of the color didn’t improve. 
My Questions:

1. How can I get the key word of white text on yellow background so that I can change the colorscheme manually? I tried already ‘highlight’ in vi which shows the keyword and the settings but it didn’t work.
2. An alternative is finding a good colorscheme for vimdiff. I found some who claimed to be optimized for vimdiff like ‘vcbc‘ but it produces the same unreadable text.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [My own colorscheme](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice) is certainly better than the one in your screenshot.

Comment: What you should probably do is change the colour profile of your terminal, instead.

Comment: Dear romainl, apprentice is the first colorscheme which produces readable code with `-d`. THANKS THAT'S IT!